# How to get the state of a checkbox certain that was auto generated from a list

Tags: python, list, checkbox, tkinter, generated

Here's the code:

```
c = len(clientlist)
for x in range(1, c):
        Checkbutton(root2, text=clientlist[x], onvalue=1).grid(row=row, column=0, sticky=W)
```

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuPxx.png)

Now, what I want to know, is how do I check if any of the checkboxes are checked. Since I can't figure out a way to give a dynamic variable to the checkbuttons. (Example: checkbox1, checkbox2, etc.)

Basically I just need to find a way to get the state from every generated checkbox - I can't figure it out.

Comment: You should explicit what library you are using (where comes `Checkbutton` class?)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use Tkinter. Try this:

```
import Tkinter as tk

chkbutton_state = {}

for chk in checkbuttons:
    var = tk.IntVar() 
    btn = Checkbutton(root2, text=chk, onvalue=1, variable=var)
    chkbutton_state[chk] = var

# render
for checkbutton in checkbuttons:
    checkbutton.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky=W)

# then somewhere else, read the state ect
print checkbutton_state
print checkbutton_state['c1']
```

And if your intention was to skip the first element of the list as the code seems suggest add after first line:

```
checkbuttons.pop(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question so quickly, even though my question might be a bit vague. I'm new to this website. But it seems to throw this error at me: `AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'state'`

Comment: Apologies, I mixed up libraries in my head. Edited my answer now - it's a bit more elaborate for Tkinter

Comment: Thanks again, but it still throws me another error:  `KeyError: 'c1'
`

Comment: ok, so comment out the last line and check what are the keys in the ouput of the print command above that - it prints the whole dict. I don't know exactly what's in your checkbuttons variable. Please use this as a guide